# -[UITextField isFirstResponder] returns false even though field is currently editing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my view controller's `-viewDidLoad` method, I call `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];`  This works like a charm, opens the keyboard and myTextField gets focus.

I have a button with a target action (the action is in the same controller) that checks `[myTextField isFirstReponder]` - but it always returns false (er, `NO` in Cocoa terms ;)).

Is that not the right way to find out if `myTextField` has the keyboard up for input?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about checking the value of the editing property, ie [myTextField isEditing]?

I think your button takes over first responder status when you tap it.

Comment: That's exactly it.  Clicking the button takes focus and technically I want to know which is currently editing, not necessarily if the window considers it first reponder.  Thanks!

Comment: This works, sure. But why isn't the `isFirstReponder`working? No one curious?

Comment: this doesn't work for me. even though the text field is clearly being edited, `isFirstResponder` and `isEditing` both return false