# after inputAccessoryView tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sender, accessoryview

I have tried the solutions at [UITextView doesn't show InputAccessoryView on first click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803267/uitextview-doesnt-show-inputaccessoryview-on-first-click/7643880#7643880)

I'm having a with a problem with a **textView** who has a **inputAccessoryView**

I want to call **[textView resignFirstResponder]** through its inputAccessoryView,so that i can close the keyboard

and there is only a **UIButton** on the **inputAccessoryView**,and the tapping the button will invoke an IBAction method call **-(IBAction)closeKeyboard:(id)sender;**

now the sender in the method is the button on the inputAccessoryView,

question is ,

how can i find out **this** textView whose inputAccessoryView has been tapped,

or just get a pointed which is pointed to **this** textView,so i can call

[textView resignFirstResponder]??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the current first responder. If you have outlets to all your text views, you can ask each one in turn

```
if ([textView1 isFirstResponder])
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Though this may give you problems depending on your button (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249849/uitextfield-isfirstresponder-returns-false-even-though-field-is-currently-edit), but I haven't experienced this), if so use the `editing` property of the text view.

Comment: thanks a lot! Your solution seems better than mine. Since this viewController has no IBOutlets and views are created all by code, so it seems to be a little more tough,